# Firebase Functions: orderBy function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

The following code works in the emulator but returns an empty array in firebase when `includeVideos` or `includeAudios` is `false`:

```
let query = db.collection("content");

if (includeVideos && !includeAudios) {
    query = query.where("type", '==', "video").orderBy("type");
}
if (includeAudios && !includeVideos) {
    query = query.where("type", '==', "audio").orderBy("type");
}
if (!includeVideos && !includeAudios) {
    return {empty json....}
}

if (matchingPersonID != undefined) {
    query = query.where("attributionID", '==', matchingPersonID).orderBy("attributionID");
}

//either categories OR matchingSeriesID is always undefined/empty
if (matchingSeriesID != undefined) {
    query = query.where("seriesIDs", 'array-contains', matchingSeriesID).orderBy("seriesIDs");
}

if (matchingCategories.length != 0) {
    // 'OR' LOGIC
    query = query.where("categories", 'array-contains-any', matchingCategories).orderBy("categories");
}

if (lastDocumentID != undefined) {
    await db.collection("content").doc(lastDocumentID).get().then((snapshot) => {
        query = query.startAfter(snapshot);
        log(`starting after document ${snapshot}`)
    })
}

//the code works when this line is removed, but the query needs to be sorted by time in order for pagination to work
query = query.orderBy("upload_date", "desc");

return query.limit(getNext).get()...
```

I get no error messages in the google cloud logs, and so I have no easy way of creating an index, if that's what I need to do.
In firestore, the fields `upload_date`, `attributionID`, `type`, `seriesIDs`, and `categories` are all on the same level in the document.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: You should throw your own error for when `matchingPersonID` and `matchingCategories` are given at the same time as using both will cause Firebase to error out, but it isn't obvious from the way you handle when both are given.

Comment: Also consider using the modular Firebase V9 syntax if you can as each constraint can be added to an array and then merged into the query all at once. This allows you to avoid redefining query on every other line and switch it to using `const`.

Comment: I do throw an error but I didn't post that code. Thanks though!

Comment: I tried figuring out how to upgrade to v9 but I cant seem to figure it out. Does it mean I need to rewrite all my functions?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that the `orderBy` on `type` and `attributionID` will throw an error because you are using them with equalities. Regarding upgrading to v9, you can import the compatibility library to gradually migrate your code by importing `firebase/compat/app`, `firebase/compat/firestore` and so on. Then when you want to use the modern syntax import `firebase/firestore` and so on.

Comment: Which [data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) are you using for the `upload_date` field?
Could you share a sample of the data you are using to test the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you comment, it seems that an **index** for that field is missing.

[This documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) mentions two ways to handle these indexes:

- By using the CLI. You can bring your indexes to a local file in a JSON format. For this, run `firebase firestore:indexes` inside your firebase project folder, you'll get a formatted JSON output for you to copy, add a new one and then deploy them with `firebase deploy --only firestore:indexes`.
- Indeed, you can use the URL generated by Firebase when it catches the error of using an index that does not exist, but you can also do it by hand from the Firebase console of the application:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't figure out which fields to put in or the order in which to put them in. I couldn't get it to work. Are you sure it's possible?

Comment: @DavidReese You would need to create indexes for each combination that your query uses, in the order they are added to the query. Semicolon-delimited they are: `seriesID:asc, upload_date:desc; categories:array, upload_date:desc; attributionID:asc, upload_date:desc; attributionID:asc, seriesID:asc, upload_date:desc; attributionID:asc, categories:array, upload_date:desc; type:asc, attributionID:asc, seriesID:asc, upload_date:desc; type:asc, seriesID:asc, upload_date:desc; type:asc, attributionID:asc, upload_date:desc; type:asc, attributionID:asc, categories:array, upload_date:desc`

Comment: Does this work even with my line of code `query = query.orderBy("upload_date", "desc")`? Because it seems like no matter how many indexes I try, this line removes all the data.

Comment: Also, does it work to make the primary sorting mechanism the upload_date? I want to sort by time.